# How to serialize a List in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, serialization

I am writing a program to take several fields of a "patient" and serialize the data into XML. I am grabbing all the information as follows:

```
Dim pacients As New List(Of Patients)
Dim p As New Patients
p.mFirstName = txtFirstName.ToString
p.mlastName = txtLastName.ToString
p.mInsurance = txtInsurance.ToString
p.mDOB = txtDateOfBirth.ToString
p.mEmail = txtEmail.ToString
p.mPhone = txtPhone.ToString
p.mPlanID = txtPhone.ToString
p.mSubID = txtSubID.ToString
```

And this is the part with the big error (this is triggered by a different 'save all' button, where as the code before is part of a 'add to list' button):

```
Dim writer As New StreamWriter(PatientFileName.PatientFileName)
Dim serial As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Patients))
serial.Serialize(writer, pacients) 'in this line it just says there was an error generating the xml document
writer.Close()
```

If the patients class is required I will post it.

Comment: Have you added the `Serializable` attribute to your `Patients` class? Also, it's usually a good idea to post the full error.

Comment: I think you need to use a filestream, not streamwriter

Comment: @DeanOC That is literally all it says "There was an error generating the XML document" and "InvalidOperationException was unhandled"

Comment: make sure `PatientFileName` is a valid path and that you have access to write there

Comment: @Plutonix Yes I have permission. When I add them individually, 1 by 1 right after clicking a "save" button, it saves and appends to the file normally. It is only after I try to append a list that it throws me the error.

Comment: What does this variable hold: `PatientFileName.PatientFileName`

Comment: `Public ReadOnly PatientFileName As String = "..\..\patients.xml"` @OneFineDay

Comment: I think you are misconstruing what is going on.  You are not opening the file in append mode, it is just that there is 1, then 2 then 3 items in the list when you go one by one.  try a FileStream and open it as `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This:

```
Dim serial As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Patients))
```

Is expecting one object of patient, this needs to be changed to expect a list as follows:

```
Dim serial As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Patient)))
```

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it... you can loop through your list and call this method each time, also make sure you have the serialize attribute at the top of your patient class, its required. Also your issue is because your gettype is for your patient class, not a list of patients which your passing in to serialize. Also from the looks of code you posted your don't need a list, just use your class object and save it...

```
 Public Sub SavePatient(Byval patients As Patients)
    Dim writer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(patients))
    Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter(
  "YOURPATH.xml")
    writer.Serialize(file, patients)
    file.Close()
 End Sub
```